# Failed dependencies when installing Oracle XE to Ubuntu

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle-xe

I'm trying to follow the instructions in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm to install Oracle XE in my Ubuntu 15 virtual machine.

But when running this command:

```
sudo rpm -ivh downloads/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

I get the following error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc >= 2.3.4 is needed by oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64
    libaio >= 0.3.104 is needed by oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64
    /bin/sh is needed by oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64
```

I installed those 2 first packages by using:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

but I'm still getting that error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.de/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html. Also, it looks like you don't have the `/bin/sh` on your system (which is really strange) but you can create one by symlinking it `bash` or any other shell you like.

Comment: It's a brand new Ubuntu installation. I also found it weird though

Comment: @Munir you should just add that comment to the answers, it's a great guidance, although I just ended up using Oracle Linux instead of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a `/bin/sh` using `ln -svf bash /bin/sh`.
After that, you can follow the instructions at http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.de/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html

The gist of the instructions is:

```
unzip oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
sudo apt-get install alien libaio1 unixodbc
sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
sudo vim /sbin/chkconfig
```

In vim:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Oracle 11gR2 XE installer chkconfig hack for Ubuntu
file=/etc/init.d/oracle-xe
if [[ ! `tail -n1 $file | grep INIT` ]]; then
echo >> $file
echo '### BEGIN INIT INFO' >> $file
echo '# Provides: OracleXE' >> $file
echo '# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog' >> $file
echo '# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog' >> $file
echo '# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5' >> $file
echo '# Default-Stop: 0 1 6' >> $file
echo '# Short-Description: Oracle 11g Express Edition' >> $file
echo '### END INIT INFO' >> $file
fi
```

Back in terminal:

```
update-rc.d oracle-xe defaults 80 01
sudo chmod 755 /sbin/chkconfig
sudo vim /etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf
```

In vim:

```
# Oracle 11g XE kernel parameters  
fs.file-max=6815744  
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=9000 65000  
kernel.sem=250 32000 100 128 
kernel.shmmax=536870912
```

In terminal:

```
sudo service procps start
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk 
mkdir /var/lock/subsys 
touch /var/lock/subsys/listener 

sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
```

The blog has the full set of instructions and requirements for running Oracle. I have only provided the ones to install Oracle XE, since the question is about installation.